# Cannot Connect to a remotely ubuntu machine which contain java 1.8.0 using java VisualVM in windows

Tags: java, ubuntu, visualvm

I know question regarding this have been already asked but unfortunately I tried every thing and still didn't get any luck so I decided to post this so that I can get the direct help from you guys.

I am trying to monitor the services of java running in an ubuntu server from my local windows machine using `Java VisualVM`

```
java -version

openjdk version "1.8.0_265"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_265-8u265-b01-0ubuntu2~18.04-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.265-b01, mixed mode)
```

I search a lot through the internet and came to conclusion that I have to setup jstatd in my ubuntu server

I run this command on the terminal

```
jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jstatd.all.policy -J-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.66.0.5 -J-Djava.rmi.server.logCalltrue -p 1099
```

Where

content of **jstatd.all.policy**

```
grant codebase "file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar" {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

**10.66.0.5: Ip of my ubuntu server which I want to monitor**

When I run this command screen hang from the next line and when I open another terminal and check the status of the port 1099 like this:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :1099
```

I get this:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::1099                 :::*                    LISTEN      22188/jstatd
```

So I assume this is running fine

Problem happens when I try to connect to ubuntu server using VisualVM, so what I do is:

1. Open Java VisualVM in my windows machine
2. [image: List item]
3. Then Add Remote Host : Host name: 10.66.0.5 (ip of my ubuntu machine)

Now what?? nothing happens when right click on the remote menu and try to **add JMX connection** with this setting

[image]

I get this error:

**Cannot connect to 10.66.0.5:1099 using service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://10.66.0.5:1099/jmxrmi**

**Now what should I do how can I monitor the services that are running on my ubuntu server ??**

**Question:**

```
One more question do I need to install VisualVM also in my ubuntu machine as well ?
```

Comment: Is there a firewall running on one or both of the machines that is blocking that port?

Comment: @geocodezip thanks for replying,  I open the port from the GCP as well as from the ubuntu machine although when I check through the portchecker.com status of the port is close I don't know why ?

Comment: That would be a different question.  I see you added a second question to this one, please only ask one question per question.